# Deferred Promises in PromiseJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that I loop through creating a promise for each one, and then add the promise to another array of promises. I then pass those promises to `Promise.all` and wait for them to complete. What I want to do is add a delay to each so their execution is deferred.

Here's my code:

```
function updateStatus(message) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        var params = { status: message };
        twitter.post('statuses/update', params, function(error, tweet, response) {
            if(error) reject(error);
            else fulfill(tweet);
        });
    });
}
```

Thats my promise. Later I loop through an array of promotions and add them to a promises array:

```
fetchPromotions.then(function(promotions) {

    var promises = [];

    for(var i=0; i < promotions.length; i++) {
        promises.push(updateStatus(promotion[i].text));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(...);
```

I then wait for them to complete using `Promise.all()`.

What I want to do is add a delay to each promise. So the first runs right away, the second 1 minute later, the third 2 minutes later etc.

Is this possible with PromiseJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **setTimeout** function to set a delay for each promise.

```
function generate(delay, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(`Promise ${id} with ${delay} delay`);
    }, delay);
  });
}

const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  promises.push(generate(i * 1000, i));
}

//Wait 4s because it's the longest timer
Promise.all(promises).then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)?

```
function updateStatus(message) {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var params = { status: message };
            twitter.post('statuses/update', params, function(error, tweet, response) {
                if(error) reject(error);
                else fulfill(tweet);
            });
        }, YOUR_DELAY);

    });
}
```

**ADDED:**

You can create a delay function that returns a function that returns a promise. So you can call this function with delay parameter at `then` chains:

```
  function delay(delayInMs){
      return function (){
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){setTimeout(resolve,delayInMs);});
      }  
  }
```

Comment: Node.js, doesn't have `window` object.

Comment: I was kind of hoping PromiseJS had a solution. I will give this a try though, I'd need to pass `delay` into the function as they'd have different times.